# ms project - delay a task due to unaviability of 1 resource

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

I want to schedule tasks using multiple resources.  The work task is fixed and multiple resources are allocated to the tasks.

I want to auto-schedule the tasks, however, when 1 resource is unavailable (i.e. through using exceptions in 'change working time'), I want MS project to automatically delay the task until ALL resources are available to complete the task.

i.e. I don't want MS project allocate the task to the 1 resource nor do I want the duration extended. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want MSP to **delay** the task rather than work around the off time, your only real choice is to use the resource leveler along with the resource availability matrix. I.e.

1. Block out the off-time using the resource's availability grid on the General tab of the Resource Information dialog (Leave the resource's calendar at the normal working times).  As normally scheduled, the resource may be shown as over-allocated.
2. In Leveling Options, ensure that "Leveling can adjust individual assignments..." and "Leveling can create splits..." are BOTH un-checked.  Then run the leveler manually.  (You could run it automatically, but then you lose track.)

[image: Leveling Options]
[image: Comparison of Resource Calendar vs. Availability/Leveling]

Comment: Note:  This is a pretty unconventional approach for project scheduling, and there are a number of potential issues.  (E.g. the finest resolution is daily.)  I wouldn't get in the habit of using it.  Most issues can be solved with a mix of resource and task calendars.